# Deep Update and Delete operations on Array of Objects Using Lodash

Tags: javascript, node.js, lodash, node-modules

I'm building NodeJS application that requires me to play with objects like this -

```
var userObject = {
    userName: "jon",
    type: "user",
    active: true,
    category: null,
    userRelationships: [{ // one level deep array of Objects
            relationshipId: 121,
            relationshipStatus: "none",
            relationshipType: "colleague",
            lastUpdate: 2018 - 02 - 01,
            interactions: 0
        },
        {
            relationshipId: 12121,
            relationshipStatus: null,
            relationshipType: "colleague",
            lastUpdate: 2018 - 02 - 06,
            interactions: 0
        },
        ...
    ],
    userInteractions: [{
        interactionId: 121211,
        interactionStatus: "pending",
        owner: 12458,
        interactionDetails: [{ // two level deep array of Objects
                interactionDetailId: 754,
                parentInteractionId: 121211,
                detailsType: "interaction"

            },
            {
                interactionDetailId: 735,
                parentInteractionId: 121211,
                detailsType: "interaction"

            },
            ....
        ]
    }]
};
```

I'm using lodash for object manipulation. There are frequent cases when I'm required to Add/ Remove/ Manipulate properties in an array of objects which are further nested into array of objects and so on up to 2 level deep.
How can I achieve this (using lodash) without writing `for..in` and `for..of` loops again and again?
I'm open to other suggestions as well.
Thank you

Comment: Can you give an example of a manipulation? Are the nested objects of the same type?

Comment: Yes! all nested objects are array and every array is an array of objects as shown above in the question. Object manipulations like, adding a property to each object inside of every nested array and so on OR modifying values of properties that occur in every object no matter how nested the object is.

Comment: Not sure if i understand what you desire, but you can always find the index of the element that you want to manipulate and do whatever you want with it. For example `let index = userObject.userRelationships.findIndex(item => item.relationshipId === 121); userObject.userRelationships[index].relationshipStatus = "bla"`